# Async calls on Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing a mic plugin for a game and since the `[capture_session startRunning]` function is a long call, I'm wrapping it in an async call, but it is still laggy.

Commenting the code solves the lag, so I'm pretty sure this is the chunk that causes it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   [capture_session startRunning];
   is_recording = true;
                        
   NSMutableDictionary *event = [Utils newEvent:EVENT_NAME];
   event[PHASE_KEY] = @"started";
   event[IS_ERROR_KEY] = @((bool)false);
   [Utils dispatchEvent:lua_listener event:event];
});
```

Btw, I don't know much the language so I could be doing some very silly things here.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Unclear what the issue is. Of course you're right that startSession is slow and blocks, and you're right to call it on a background thread so as not to block the main thread; the docs _ tell_ you to do that, although you should not be using a global queue. But that's not going to stop the call from being slow — that's impossible — so what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    ...
    NSLog(@"current thread ---%@", [NSThread currentThread]);

});
```

You use concurrent queue and async method, those code you put in block should be run in a new thread.